# Stack Overflow for DateTime with spray-json, Slick and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, akka-http, spray-json

Hope you can help me figure this one out, please. Using Akka HTTP, Slick and PosgreSQL, I'm trying to implement a bulletin board as an excercise. You can find the latest version of it in [here for a full picture](https://github.com/michaltrzesimiech/scala-textboard).

---

**What I do have, in short:**

I have tables like these:

```
final class Posts(tag: Tag) extends Table[Post](tag, "POSTS") with CustomColumnTypes {
  def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def threadId = column[Long]("THREAD_ID")
  def secretId = column[String]("SECRET")
  def pseudonym = column[String]("PSEUDONYM")
  def email = column[String]("EMAIL")
  def content = column[String]("CONTENT")
  def created = column[DateTime]("CREATED")

final class Threads(tag: Tag) extends Table[Thread](tag, "THREADS") {
  def threadId = column[Long]("THREAD_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def subject = column[String]("SUBJECT")
```

and domain model:

```
case class Post(
    postId: Option[Long] = None,
    threadId: Option[Long],
    secretId: String,
    pseudonym: String,
    email: String,
    content: String,
    created: DateTime = DateTime.now)

case class Thread(
    threadId: Option[Long] = None, 
    subject: String

case class NewThreadWithPost(
    postId: Option[Long] = None,
    subject: String,
    secretId: String,
    pseudonym: String,
    email: String,
    content: String)
```

with custom protocol written out like this:

```
trait TextboardJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport with DateTimeHelper {
  implicit object DateTimeFormat extends RootJsonFormat[DateTime] {
    def read(value: JsValue) = value match {
      case dt: JsValue => value.convertTo[DateTime]
      case _ => deserializationError("DateTime expected")
    }
    def write(c: DateTime) = JsString(c.toString)
  }

  implicit val threadFormat = jsonFormat2(Thread.apply)
  implicit val postFormat = jsonFormat7(Post.apply)
  implicit val newThread = jsonFormat6(NewThread.apply)
}
```

and the routes like this:

```
  def route: Route = {
...
          post {
            entity(as[Post]) { post =>
              complete(createPost(Some(threadId), post).toJson) }
...
          post {
            entity(as[NewThread]) { thread =>
              (master ? CreateNewThread(thread)).mapTo[NewThread]
              complete(StatusCodes.Created) }
...
```

---

**What I intend to do and where it fails:**

I intend to add new Thread and new Post using this method, and it works great:

```
  def createNewThread(nt: NewThread) = {
    exec(threads += Thread(None, nt.subject))
    exec(posts += Post(None, lastId, secretId, nt.pseudonym, nt.email, nt.content, DateTime.now))
  }
```

What does not work at all is this seemingly alike method I use to create Posts:

```
  def createPost(threadId: Option[Long], p: Post) = {
    exec(posts returning posts.map(_.secretId)
      += Post(None, p.threadId, secretId, p.pseudonym, p.email, p.content, DateTime.now))
  }
```

---

**What happens?**

```
[error] Uncaught error from thread [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[default]
[error] java.lang.StackOverflowError
[error] at main.scala.textboard.TextboardJsonProtocol$DateTimeFromat$.read(Protocol.scala:22)
[info] [ERROR] [SECURITY][12/11/2016 23:03:22.301] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl
(default)] Uncaught error from thread [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled    [error] at spray.json.JsValue.convertTo(JsValue.scala:31) <- repeated tens of times
[error] at main.scala.textboard.TextboardJsonProtocol$DateTimeFormat$.read(Protocol.scala:23) <- repeated tens of times
[error] at main.scala.textboard.TextboardJsonProtocol$DateTimeFormat$.read(Protocol.scala:21) <- repeated tens of times
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code returned from runner: -1 at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code returned from runner: -1
[error] Total time: 18 s, completed 2016-12-11 23:19:16
```

---

**What I already tried**

- Tried to isolate the reason for which this doesn't happen when I use createNewThread().
- Tinkered with RootJsonFormat[DateTime] to fix the implicit reader.
- Tinkered with the DSL route to enable or avoid of using actors.
- Tried to avoid of passing threadId as Option.

Answer (score 5):

You got yourself an infinite loop in `DateTimeFormat`. You are calling `convertTo` within your `read`, and `convertTo` calls `read` (see [spray-json source](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/master/src/main/scala/spray/json/JsValue.scala)).

Use something like

```
implicit object DateJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[DateTime] {

    private val parser : DateTimeFormatter = ??? // your parser here

    override def write(obj: DateTime) = JsString(parser.print(obj))

    override def read(json: JsValue) : DateTime = json match {
      case JsString(s) => parser.parseDateTime(s)
      case _ => throw new Exception("Malformed datetime")
    }
  }
```